# Given Standard Deviation and Population size, how can I calculate the number of population at mean

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

As per the title, I'd like to calculate the number of the population at mean, given a std.dev and population size.

The use case for this, is Mobile Phone push notifications.
I send the notification at time $T_0$, and the users access the app in an approximately normal distribution centered at a mean time $T_1$, with std.dev $s$.

We are deploying this to an increased population, and want to estimate the extra resources we need for the population at the mean time $T_1$.

From the formula for std.dev, I can see I need to do:

$$s^2 \cdot N = \sum (x-x_m)^2$$

I'm not sure how I can operate on the sum.

Comment: Usually, the amount of users, using your application at current time is described by Poisson distribution, not normal. That's because if you have n = 10000 users and chance that each user accesses your app this minute is p = 1/1000, the chance that you have 5 users this minute is $C_{10000}^{5} \cdot \frac{1}{1000}^5 \cdot (1-\frac{1} {1000})^{9995} = \frac{(np)^k \cdot e^{-np}}{k!}$. Or you're really interested in the case, where p (and np) is quite large? Then, indeed normal distribution is relevant.

Comment: I guarantee the distribution in access time will not be normal.  The tails will be much larger.  The normal distribution extends to values below zero.

Comment: @RossMillikan and Bob: You are both correct that the true underlying distribution of access times will be non-normal, as you can't have negative values. However, the poisson approaches a normal under some circumstances, as do a number of other positive unbounded and skewed distributions. So as a reasonable approximation, the normal may still be useful, as >99% of the probabilty of a normal RV is contained within 3 standard deviations, so you really only need an accurate fit around the mean if you are not trying to estimate tail probabilities.

Comment: Agreed, it is approximately normal, and in this case I am only interested in the peak at mean, not the tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have stated that the response times appear normal/bell-shaped around the mean time, T1, you have a couple choices to make:

1. Most importantly, your data are continuously distributed, so taken literally there will be $0$ people who will access the app at *exactly* T1. However, there is probably some time band ($\delta$) around T1 that is relevant for your system design (e.g., $T_1\pm5min$)

At this point, if you are taking T1 and the stdev as *given* values of the true response of the population of users to an app push, then the answer is rather simple: it is your population size, N, multiplied by the probability that a user will respond within $T_1 \pm \delta$ after T0. Therefore, your estimated user load during this time will be $N\{\Phi(\frac{T_1+\delta}{\sigma})-\Phi(\frac{T_1-\delta}{\sigma})\}$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function for a standard normal random variable. (i.e., Mean = 0, stdev=1)

However, if you are treating T1 and the stdev as rough estiamtes, subject to substantial error, then this is not a straightforward problem:

1. After deciding on an acceptable band around T1, you need to determine what degree of confidence you want for your prediction. Higher confidence leads to a less precise prediciton but less chance of not including the true value. Lets call your desired confidence C%.
2. Now, you need to use something called a [tolerance interval](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc263.htm) for a normally distributed population (which we will assume based on your past observations), which is an interval that will contain a certain fraction (X%) of the population with confidence level C%.However, in your case, you are actually trying to find X% given n,$\delta$, stdev, and T1 and a specified confidence level C%.

A tolerance interval for a normally distributed has a very similar form as a confidence or prediction interval: $T_1\pm K*stdev$ where K is chosen to give a C% confidence of containing X% of the population. Since you have already chosen a relevant time band around T1, (i.e, $\delta$), you alredy know the interval of interest: $T_1\pm \delta$. In this case, $K=\frac{\delta}{stdev}$, so your problem reduces to finding what proportion of the population covered, X%, gives you the correct value of K for a given level of confidence, C%. Once you've solved for X%, the estimated number of app log ins is N*X%

You will need to use a numerical computational package to solve this portion, as you will see from the complex formulae in the link I sent you.